# Toggle image button (or icon) with blazorise

Tags: blazor-server-side, blazorise

I'm using Blazorise 0.9.4.7 in a .NET 5 application.
I want to have a set of toggle buttons, for example one with Eye and when clicked the Eye transforms into an EyeSlash.

I've tried a couple of alternatives that are not working...Any advice?

```
<Icon @ref="ShowIcon" Clicked="e => Show(process)" Name="IconName.Eye" />
```

Then in the cs

```
public void Show(Process project)
{
    process.ToggleShow();
    ShowProcessIcon.Name = process.Show ? IconName.EyeSlash : IconName.Eye;
}
```

That's not working on also saying I should not assign anything to Name outside the Icon itself.

I also tried

```
<Button Clicked="e => Show(process)">
    <ChildContent>
        <Icon Name="IconName.Eye" Visibility="@(process.Show ? Visibility.Visible : 
Visibility.Invisible)"/>
        <Icon Name="IconName.EyeSlash" Visibility="@(process.Show ? Visibility.Invisible : Visibility.Visible)"/>
    </ChildContent>
</Button>
```

But doesn't work either...

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use one `Icon` and then just switch the `Name` based on the visible state.

```
<Button Clicked="@ToggleIcon">
    <Icon Name="@(visible ? IconName.Eye : IconName.EyeSlash)" />
</Button>
@code {
    bool visible;

    Task ToggleIcon()
    {
        visible = !visible;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Also, it is always better to have a `Task`-able method instead of `void`. That way Blazor will automatically trigger `StateHasChanged` for you.

Comment: It worked! thx so much!